# Understanding Joins in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a lot of trobule understanding how joins work in SQLAlchemy, or possibly SQL altogether.. The following code works, but only because of luck and trial and error. I am not sure why it is producing the desired result.

In this case I wanted to get a list of Students for the current Instructor, all the instructor and student keys are join in a association table.. like so..

```
class Stud(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stud'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    cell = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    home = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    birthday = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=True)
    handicap = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=True)
    years_playing = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=True)
    opt_in = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    profile = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)


stud_inst_link = db.Table('stud_inst_link',
                          db.Column('inst_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('inst.id')),
                          db.Column('stud_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stud.id')))


class Inst(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'inst'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    cell = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    home = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    email_sig = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    birthday = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    tax_rate = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    opt_in = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    profile = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    studs = db.relationship('Stud', secondary=stud_inst_link,
                            backref=db.backref('students', lazy='dynamic'))
```

The code that finally produced the result I want was this;

```
inst_id = 20
studs =   Stud.query.join(stud_inst_link).filter(stud_inst_link.c.inst_id == inst_id).all()
for x in studs:
    print(x.first_name)
```

It gave me the list of every student in the association table who is linked with instructor with id 20. However my program looks like it will have plenty of these joins and before continuing I would love to have a better understand of what is actually happening here.

Any help would be much appreicated.

Comment: So what is your specific question? How do joins work? To evaluate `a JOIN b ON <criteria>`, take the cartesian product of the rows in `a` and the rows in `b`, and only keep the rows for which the `ON` clause is `true`.

Comment: That helps clarify it a bit. Thank you. What if you had 5 joins in a query? Can you filter multiple times, or can you only check all 5 against one criteria?

Comment: Joins are left-associative, so `a JOIN b ON ... JOIN c ON ...` is equivalent to `(a JOIN b ON ...) JOIN c ON ...`, so you can apply the previous rule one join at a time.